# Cant get RASPI pin to toggle

Tags: python, raspbmc

Hi I am testing my new raspi pins .
with the following  code am able to toggle all the ports except LED3 ..pin 16  .

Is their a method to identify if the pin itself i broker or not

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
LED1 = 20
LED2 = 21
LED3 = 16
LED4 = 12



while True:

    GPIO.setup(LED1,GPIO.OUT)
    GPIO.output(LED1,True)

    GPIO.setup(LED2,GPIO.OUT)
    GPIO.output(LED2,True)

    GPIO.setup(LED3,GPIO.OUT)
    GPIO.output(LED3,True)

    GPIO.setup(LED4,GPIO.OUT)
    GPIO.output(LED4,True)

    time.sleep(1)

    GPIO.setup(LED1,GPIO.OUT)
    GPIO.output(LED1,False)

    GPIO.setup(LED2,GPIO.OUT)
    GPIO.output(LED2,False)

    GPIO.setup(LED3,GPIO.OUT)
    GPIO.output(LED3,False)

    GPIO.setup(LED4,GPIO.OUT)
    GPIO.output(LED4,False)

    time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: Which model Pi?  If you are not sure tell us the result of this command grep Rev /proc/cpuinfo

Answer (score 1):

### Software

You could use the wiringPi library(you may have to install it) as described in this [question](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/26064/is-my-pis-gpio-damaged).  It tests input, output, pull-up and pull-down. It will return `Failed user gpios: None`if all your pins are OK.

### Hardware

Also, if it returns all clear, make sure that you are observing polarity for LED3. In other words, if you have it in the wrong way it will not work(longer lead is positive).