# npm rpi-gpio installation failed with multiple error messages, why?

Tags: raspbian, rpi.gpio, node.js

I'm using Raspberry Pi model b Type 3 with ARM7 processor. I checked the internet connection, and i tried to install the npm rpi-gpio multiple times even after restarting the pi. I'm using Raspbian jessie installed witnoobs. npm have also generated a log file.

The image of the error messages are as below,
[image]

What could be the reason. How to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my case, I solved this by installing an other version of `node` with the procedure described on [adafruit webpage](https://learn.adafruit.com/node-embedded-development/installing-node-dot-js).
I get this link from the [npn page of rpi-gpio](https://www.npmjs.com/package/rpi-gpio)

You should remove node and npm with `sudo apt-get autoremove --purg npm node` then install node according to adafruit instructions and then run `npm install rpi-gipo`